# jQuery AJAX post request issue - cannot get to root directory

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.post("./ajax.php", { action: "formID", firstname: firstname_val, email: email_val })
```

The `ajax.php` file works but only from the homepage etc..

Can anyone suggest why this isn't going to the file directly in the root?
In other parts of the site it appends the current url eg `/page/ajax.php`.

Comment: your question is not very clear. can you expalin your problem better.

Comment: Sorry - i did rush that somewhat
I have an ajax post request which works fine with a full absolute path, but doesn't work when I use a relative path eg

$.post("http://mysite.com/mail.php", { action: "maila", firstname: firstname_val, email: email_val },

$.post("./mail.php", { action: "maila", firstname: firstname_val, email: email_val },

The first one works - but the latter doesn't for some reason.

Comment: try this just this "ajax.php"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the dot out from before the slash:

```
$.post("/ajax.php", { action: "formID", firstname: firstname_val, email: email_val },
```

Answer (score 1):

you have point before slash . Point means current directory. Remove the point and requests will be sent to the root